# how do you change color of nested css element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

```
<a id='123' href='www.stackoverflow.com'>
Hello <span style='color:#c0c0c0;text-decoration: underline;'>World</span>
</a> ​
```

I currently change the link color by doing this

```
var chosenclass = document.getElementById('123');
chosenclass.style.color = '#000000';
```

But now I'd like to change the span by only having a reference to the chosenclass object.
How can I do that ?

Comment: 123 is an invalid id :) If I am not mistaken they should start with a letter.

Answer (score 3):

```
chosenclass.children[0].style.color = '#000';
```

Comment: except `children[0]` is going to be a text node and not the span, I believe.

Comment: No, `children` refers only to element children. `childNodes` includes text.